# Azure - Create a Tag with multiple values and apply it to a resource group using json

Tags: json, azure

Hi Looking for a json file to create a tag with multiple value and apply one of the value when resource group gets created
Example

Tag name - Department|
Value1  - Technology|
Value2 - Finance|
Value3 - Manufacturing|
Value4 - Sales and Marketing|
I want to create a resource with name "Test-RG" and pass one of four TAG values to RG
Say "Technology"
ANy help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your need, following the [official documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69941259/azure-create-a-tag-with-multiple-values-and-apply-it-to-a-resource-group-using), you can parametrize the tags :

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "rgName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the resourceGroup to create"
      }
    },
    "rgLocation": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[deployment().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for the resourceGroup"
      }
    },
    "resourceTags": {
      "type": "object"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('rgName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('rgLocation')]",
      "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]",
      "properties": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Then all you need is to pass a JSON object for `resourceTags` parameter when deploying the ARM template. You can either do it [inline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-powershell#inline-parameters) or using [parameter files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-use-parameter-file?tabs=azure-powershell#add-parameter-files).

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this and let you know.